Bootstrap5 Toggle No Event Response With jQuery.Clone(True)
I enjoy the practicality of  Bootstrap5 Toggle plugin. The purpose of plugin provide user the option to toggle from one Module A to Module B. Each line item is wrap under DIV class .lineitem-wrapper.
Other elements in .lineitem-wrapper includes span and input text which are link to events. Work like a charm.
However, the issue comes with the clone elements of lineitem-wrapper and the toggle plugin stop responding. The other elements like span and input text events are working absolutely fine.


$('.btn-lineitem-add-stkgl').on('click', function(e) {

  //clone with event the last lineitem-wrapper 
  new_lineitemStkGL = $('.lineitems-wrapper').last().find('.lineitem-wrapper').clone(true);
  //....

  //tried the destroy and initialize method but same error
  // $('.check-moduleId').bootstrapToggle('destroy');
  //$('.check-moduleId').bootstrapToggle();

  $('.lineitems-wrapper').append(new_lineitemStkGL);
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-Ez0cGzNzHR1tYAv56860NLspgUGuQw16GiOOp/I2LuTmpSK9xDXlgJz3XN4cnpXWDmkNBKXR/VDMTCnAaEooxA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-EKWWs1ZcA2ZY9lbLISPz8aGR2+L7JVYqBAYTq5AXgBkSjRSuQEGqWx8R1zAX16KdXPaCjOCaKE8MCpU0wcHlHA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.1.1/css/bootstrap5-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.1.1/js/bootstrap5-toggle.ecmas.min.js"></script>

<div class="row"><div class="col"><a href="#" class="btn btn-otline-dark me-0  rounded-1  btn-lineitem-add-stkgl"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus "></i> Add new item</a></div></div>


<div class="row lineitems-wrapper mb-1">
  <div class="row lineitem-wrapper mb-1">
    <!-- line item module by toggle -->
    <div class="col-1 m-0">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="pm-0 check-moduleId"
        data-size="sm"
        checked
        data-toggle="toggle"
        data-onlabel="GL"
        data-offlabel="STK"
        data-onstyle="primary"
        data-offstyle="warning">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 pm-0 ">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lineitem-code px-1 " placeholder="Select Stock / GL ">
        <!-- the stkgl edit btn -->
        <div class="input-group-prepend position-relative">
          <span class="input-group-text text-primary mdi mdi-magnify border-bottom-0 px-1 btn-lineitem-edit-stkgl cursor-pointer"> </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




Since the question isn't really crystal clear, I did put some efforts to make your code a live snippet including all the supposed assets still missing (bootstrap5 css, jquery and the bootstrap5 toggle plugin coming from github ). Please make more clear what is working and what is not working according to expectations because so far it's still not easy to understand

Appreciate that. Also the button which trigger the clone event has been added to complete the sample.

The issue you are having when attempting to clone the last row to append a new row to the target area, is because the bootstrap-toggle component needs to be initialized over the corresponding input type="checkbox".
Such stage happens when the page is loaded, and all elements already existing at that time and matching the criteria, will be changed as bootstrap-toggles.
If you try to clone such a row having its inner toggle already initialized, will cause you to clone the whole toggle initialized for the original row and it will be messed up for its new role in a different row.
So what you need to do to achieve that result, is having a template element describing a row, that won't be affected by the initialization stage occuring at page load so that you will be using this one to create your clones that will be initialized on demand at the time of appending.
I created a very simple demo to show a simple scenario...

All I did was creating a template element embedding your row:

<template> : The Content Template element

The  HTML element serves as a mechanism for holding HTML
fragments, which can either be used later via JavaScript or generated
immediately into shadow DOM.


Then I used the content property of the HTMLTemplateElement to fetch its content:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content

The HTMLTemplateElement.content property returns a 
element's template contents (a DocumentFragment).


And used the bootstrapToggle() bootstrap-toggle - methods over the new input element to initialize the toggle on the newly added row



$('.btn-lineitem-add-stkgl').on('click', function(e) {        
    
    //fetch the content of the template row
    const templateContent = $('#row').prop('content');    
    
    //clone its elements
    const newLineItem = $(templateContent).children().clone(true);    
    
    //append the cloned elements to the target area
    $('.lineitems-wrapper').append(newLineItem);    
    
    //initialize the bootstrap toggle on the new row by calling the corresponding method on the input element
    newLineItem.find('.check-moduleId')[0].bootstrapToggle();  
});
<!-- bootstrap.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-Ez0cGzNzHR1tYAv56860NLspgUGuQw16GiOOp/I2LuTmpSK9xDXlgJz3XN4cnpXWDmkNBKXR/VDMTCnAaEooxA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- jquery.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!-- bootstrap.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-EKWWs1ZcA2ZY9lbLISPz8aGR2+L7JVYqBAYTq5AXgBkSjRSuQEGqWx8R1zAX16KdXPaCjOCaKE8MCpU0wcHlHA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!-- bootstrap5-toggle.min.js -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.1.1/css/bootstrap5-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- bootstrap5-toggle.ecmas.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.1.1/js/bootstrap5-toggle.ecmas.min.js"></script>

<!-- add new item button -->
<div class="row mx-2 my-2">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-1 btn-lineitem-add-stkgl">
      <i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus"></i> Add new item
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- target zone for appending new items -->
<div class="row lineitems-wrapper mx-1">    
</div>

<!-- template for new row to be appended -->
<template id="row">
  <div class="row lineitem-wrapper mb-1">    
    <div class="col-2">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="pm-0 check-moduleId"
        data-size="sm"
        checked
        data-toggle="toggle"
        data-onlabel="GL"
        data-offlabel="STK"
        data-onstyle="primary"
        data-offstyle="warning">
    </div>      
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lineitem-code px-1" placeholder="Select Stock / GL ">        
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</template>




Props to the 
I was kind of  using the last row as a sort of "template" but it is messy and the .boostrapToggle() create a toggle on top of toggle.  The values of the cloned elements need resetting too.
Curiosity kicks in the sample code -  newLineItem.find('.check-moduleId')[0].bootstrapToggle();  I did not find indexes in input  .check-moduleId element.  Should newLineItem.find('.check-moduleId').bootstrapToggle(); not enough to initialize the bootstrapToggle?

Don't forget we are using jQuery here! so when you use the $ function with a selector, the object returned will be a jQuery object and not directly the original vanilla HTMLElement.  To retrieve the underneath vanilla element we need to use [0] over that object so then we can call the bootstrapToogle() method over it to initialize the bootstrap-toggle component. I used jQuery to mimic your scenario as close as possible.
